# Julia, integer vs boolean results from selection of instances in two arrays

Tags: arrays, boolean, conditional-statements, julia

I've got my 3d array called Pop.  I want find out how many times two different conditions are met, and they both work for me independently but I can't put the two together.

```
Pop[end, :, 1] .== 3
```

works ok, produces an integer vector of 1's and 0's which is correct.  Also

```
Pop[end-1, :, 1] .== 4
```

works, again returns integer vector, however when I put the two together as:

```
count(Pop[end, :, 1] .== 3 && Pop[end-1, :, 1] .== 4)
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR: TypeError: non-boolean (BitArray{1}) used in boolean context
```

Which sort of helps, can see that the two numeric arrays can not be compared in a boolean way.  What is wrong with my syntax to get the count of the number of times both of the conditions are met.  Simple I know but I can't get it!  Thx. J

Comment: You want `(Pop[end, :, 1] .== 3) .& (Pop[end-1, :, 1] .== 4)`. Be warned that without the brackets, the precedence is different: compare `:(1 == 2 & 3 == 4) |> dump` to the same with `&&`.

Comment: Thx mcabbot, I do try to find examples and/or explanations but it seems the language is so new that there is little out there. Where would I find description of difference between `.&` and `&&`?

Comment: `&&` is like `? :` without the else case, it's described here: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/control-flow/ . Whereas `&` is just a function, described here: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/mathematical-operations/ . The manual is pretty good on the whole, although of course you need not read to the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&&` is a short-circuiting boolean, which means that if the first term is `true`, the rest isn't evaluated (see [documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/control-flow/#Short-Circuit-Evaluation)). It also means it's only for a singular booleans and it cannot be broadcasted over an array.

`&` is the bitwise AND operator ([documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/mathematical-operations/#Bitwise-Operators)), that you want to use here, because it can be broadcasted over arrays with the syntax `.&`, the same way you use `.==`

```
julia> [true, true, false, false] .& [true, false, true, false]
4-element BitVector:
 1
 0
 0
 0
```

**Update**

in Julia 1.7+, the short-circuiting operators `&&` and `||` can now be dotted to participate in broadcast fusion as `.&&` and `.||` ([#39594](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/39594)):

```
julia> [true, true, false, false] .&& [true, false, true, false]
4-element BitVector:
 1
 0
 0
 0
```